# Can ice patterns form on the top of deep water?

Tags: solid-state-physics, water, phase-transition, ice

Here is a picture of a pattern in ice:

[image]

There are feathers, or flowers to be seen. The ice has grown on a solid underground. Water condenses on the solid underground and freezes. I have never seen this pattern on the ice of a pool of water. Say a rain pool or a lake. But I could be wrong. Maybe these patterns *can* develop on a thick layer of water. How do these structures develop? Is it necessary for their development that there is a solid underground on which the ice can develop or can the pattern develop on a water pool too? Can they develop if the bottom of a body of water is cooled first?

Answer (score 1):

The nice ice crystals in the picture tend to form on surfaces where there is only a small amount of water (or water available as vapour in the air). They grow in competition (leaving contrasting empty space where there is no ice) and have ice form preferentially at their tips (producing dendritic patterns). Frost crystals are the 3D version of this, typically occurring on surfaces exposed to moist but cold air.

When a water surface freezes ice crystals may start branching, but since there is never any shortage of water they keep on growing until they meet. Eventually the whole surface is covered and the pattern becomes invisible. An exception is some puddles where freezing can produce long blade-like crystals, but as they form the surface level of the water sinks (due to evaporation or freezing elsewhere) making the net of blades remain visible.